# Get the value from array using laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, frameworks

This is the sample array

```
Array
(
    [note] => Array
        (
            [to] => Array
                (
                    [user] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => First User
                        )

                    [abc] => 123
                    [lmn] => 4582
                )

            [from] => Jani
            [heading] => Reminder
            [body] => Array
                (
                    [abc] => 123
                )

        )

)
```

I have a string like "note > to > abc" and want value of "abc" under "to" array. So how can I get the value?

Comment: Use a foreach loop..

Comment: Just that value can be `$arr['note']['to']['abc']`

Comment: If you're using laravel, there is a helper method that can be used, named [`data_get()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-data-get). `data_get($arr, 'note.to.abc)`

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI I think that should be the answer rather than just a comment

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes you're right, but the title of the question was about php in general. I posted it as answer and edited the title to specifically point to laravel.

Comment: There was a Laravel tag +1

Answer (score 5):

In laravel, there is a helper method named `data_get()` for getting a specific key without throwing error if it doesn't exists.

It is documented [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-data-get)

You can use it like below:

```
data_get($arr, 'note.to.abc)
```